# How to Stop Simultaneous click on submit button

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, double-click

here is the snapshot link: http://postimg.org/image/ul84henil/

#### What I need:

1. I would like a **dblclick** in the ***Budget*** and ***Expense*** `<td>`'s, respectively, to hide the `p.budgetVal` and show the `form` in only *ITS OWN* `<td>`.
2. Additionally, it would be nice to also reset the opposing/corresponding `<td>` so that:

   1. its `p.budgetVal` appears again (if it was hidden) and,
   2. its `form` is hidden (if it was shown)

#### My Problem/Current State:

The `.budget` class `dblclick` is working ok but the `dblclick` event on the **Expense** `<td>` causes the **budget table cell's form** to open as well/simultaneously.

***Here is my code :***

```
  <tr class="nofirst">
    <td title="<?php
                 echo $project_store_row['Name'].
                      "[".$project_store_row['Name'].
                      "]";
               ?>"
    >
      <div class="bigtd">
        <a href="https://app.a.com
                   <?php  ?>
                   /0/
                   <?php
                     echo $project_store_row['Project_ID'];
                   ?>"
           target="_blank"
           style="color:#282828"><?php echo $project_store_row['Name']; ?>
        </a>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td class="Budget" title="budget">
      <p class="budgetVal">
        <?php echo $project_store_row['Budget']; ?>
      </p>
      <form style="display:none">
        <input type="text" class="budget_val" style="width:30px">
        <input type="button"
               id="<?php echo $project_store_row['Project_ID'];?>"
               class="btn" value="Ok"
        >
      </form>
    </td>
    <td class="Expense">
      <p class="budgetVal">
        <?php echo $project_store_row['Expense']; ?>
      </p>
      <form style="display:none">
        <input type="text" class="budget_val" style="width:30px">
        <input type="button"
               id="<?php echo $project_store_row['Project_ID'];?>"
               class="btn" value="Ok"
        >
      </form>
    </td>
```

- and here is my jquery Code:

  ```
                $(".Budget").dblclick(function(){
                          $(this).parent().find('.budgetVal').hide();
                          $(this).parent().find('form').show('slow');
                      });

                       $(".Expense").dblclick(function(){

                          alert("hello");
                          $(this).parent().find('.budgetVal').hide();
                          $(this).parent().find('form').show('slow');
                          $(this).parent().parent().child().find('.Budget').hide();

                      });
  ```

Comment: whats the issue here now ?

Comment: i just want that link 1 (click on link1 form is opened ok). link 2 click  (form is opened ok) but problem- link 1 form should be close if isty how

Comment: the way you were traversing the DOM structure was wrong, inside the `.expense` classes element double click handler,you were referring to form inside `.budget` class element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Your problem/mistake:

---

- You have **BOTH** `dblclick` event handlers for **Budget** and **Expense**, referencing their **respective** parents.
- The issue is that:

  - the respective parents are the **SAME parent**, i.e. the table row `<tr class="nofirst">`.
  - Then you are trying to **`.find()`** **budgetVal** and **`.hide()`** it (which probably works in both cases)
  - Then you are trying to find() the generic form "child" and showing it ==> here is your problem:

    - You see, since in both cases, you are going to the same parent,
    - then this statement:

      > `$(this).parent().find('form').show('slow');`

      will always show the "budget" form, because it is the **first form** *found* that is a **child** of the **`<tr>`**.

.

### Solution(s):

---

You have **2 options:**

1. Navigate the DOM to the **first** (for *Budget*) and **second** (for *Expense*) `form` using the proper selector in your jQuery like so:

   ```
   parent.find('form:first')
   ```

   and

   ```
   parent.find('form:second')
   ```
2. Modify your HTML to include `id` attributes for the `<form>` tags like below, and modify your jQuery to find them explicitly **OR** since they are both in the same `<td>`, you *DO NOT* need to go to the **parent** at all.

   **HTML**

   ```
   <tr class="nofirst">
     <td title="<?php 
                  echo $project_store_row['Name'].
                       "[".$project_store_row['Name'].
                       "]";
                ?>"
     >
       <div class="bigtd">
         <a href="https://app.a.com
                    <?php  ?>
                    /0/
                    <?php 
                      echo $project_store_row['Project_ID']; 
                    ?>" 
            target="_blank" 
            style="color:#282828"><?php echo $project_store_row['Name']; ?>
         </a>
       </div>
     </td>
     <td class="Budget" title="budget">
       <p class="budgetVal">
         <?php echo $project_store_row['Budget']; ?>
       </p>
       <form id="#budget_form" style="display:none">
         <input type="text" class="budget_val" style="width:30px">
         <input type="button" 
                id="<?php echo $project_store_row['Project_ID'];?>" 
                class="btn" value="Ok"
         >
       </form>
     </td>
     <td class="Expense">
       <p class="budgetVal">
         <?php echo $project_store_row['Expense']; ?>
       </p>
       <form id="#expense_form" style="display:none">
         <input type="text" class="budget_val" style="width:30px">
         <input type="button" 
                id="<?php echo $project_store_row['Project_ID'];?>" 
                class="btn" value="Ok"
         >
       </form>
     </td>
   ```

   **jQuery**

   ...again, you can reference the `form` using its the explicit id, e.g. `$('form#budget_form')` **OR** since they are both in the same `<td>`, you *DO NOT* need to go to the **parent** at all:

   ```
     $(".Budget").dblclick(function(){
       $(this).find('.budgetVal').hide();
       $(this).find('form').show('slow');

       // reset the other TD when you click in this one.
       $(".Expense").find('.budgetVal').show();  
       $(".Expense").find('form').hide();
     });

     $(".Expense").dblclick(function(){
       $(this).find('.budgetVal').hide();
       $(this).find('form').show('slow');

       // reset the other TD when you click in this one.
       $(".Budget").find('.budgetVal').show();  
       $(".Budget").find('form').hide();
     });
   ```

   - **Notice**, I also added a bit of code below to reset the other `<td>` to re-show, and re-hide the value and form, respectively.
   - **Further**, you could make use of jQuery **`.toggle()`** to achieve the same effect.

Comment: thanks sr for help and givivg exact concept about dom ..cheers it worked

Answer (score 0):

You're using jQuery so use the preventDefault() and the toggle() function (http://api.jquery.com/toggle/).

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#form1').click(function(e) {
        $(e).preventDefault();
        $('#form1').toggle();
        $('#form2').toggle();
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The way your traversing is wrong , try this way

```
                $(".Expense").dblclick(function(){
                    alert("hello");
                    $('.budgetVal').hide() // hide all budgetVal element which is open
                    //$(this).parent().find('.budgetVal').hide();
                    //$(this).parent().find('form').show('slow'); // here your referring to `.budget` classes form 
                    $('form').hide('slow'); //this will close all open forms
                    $(this).find('form').show('slow'); // this will show the form inside `.expense` class element
                    $(this).parent().find('.Budget').hide();

                });
```

Happy Coding :)